# Endpoint for logging in?

Tags: java, php, jsoup

JSoup Login to website AND then open another page KEEPING that login session.

Could anyone explain how to log in on [this website](http://www.rlo.nl/roostersinfoweb/infoweb/index.php) using JSoup?

My code currently (Completely fails, I'm sure I'm on the wrong 'track'):

```
Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("http://www.rlo.nl/roostersinfoweb/infoweb/index.php")
.method(Connection.Method.GET)
.execute();


Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.rlo.nl/roostersinfoweb/infoweb/index.php").get();Jsoup.connect("http://www.rlo.nl/roostersinfoweb/infoweb/authentication.php")
.data("cookieexists", "false")
.data("username", "110")
.data("password", "sgl16")
.data("login", "Login")
.cookies(loginForm.cookies())
.post();
```

One thing I'm sure of: authentication.php doesn't exist.

I am new to JSoup, so please explain some code and tell me about the 'cookie' part (I know what cookies are, but not how you use them with JSoup.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some points to correct:

- the login endpoint is not correct (the correct one is `http://www.gymnasiumleiden.nl/roostersinfoweb/infoweb/index.php`);
- some `POST` parameters you're sending are misspelled (e.g. `username` should be `user`);
- some `POST` parameters are not required (e.g. `cookieexists`);
- you're not adding the required `csrf` parameter in the `POST` request.
- you should check the response to understand if login is ok or not.

My working code (with an error checker):

```
Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup
  .connect("http://www.gymnasiumleiden.nl/roostersinfoweb/infoweb/index.php")
  .method(Connection.Method.GET)
  .execute();

Document doc = loginForm.parse();
String csrf = doc.select("input[name=csrf]").val();
Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect("http://www.gymnasiumleiden.nl/roostersinfoweb/infoweb/index.php")
        .data("user", "110638")
        .data("paswoord", "sgl1617")
        .data("login", "loginform")
        .data("csrf", csrf)
        .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
        .method(Connection.Method.POST)
        .execute();
String body = response.body();
if(body.contains("Wachtwoord is incorrect")){
    System.out.println("Password incorrect!");
} else if(body.contains("Gebruikersnaam werd niet gevonden.")){
    System.out.println("Not found username!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Login successfully!");          
}
```

Comment: [https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-automate-login-a-website-java-example/](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-automate-login-a-website-java-example/) and  [http://www.javacodeexamples.com/jsoup-login-to-website-using-post-method-example/830](http://www.javacodeexamples.com/jsoup-login-to-website-using-post-method-example/830) nice tutorials, But @davide can add his own suggestions also

Comment: Experience in [Neembuu Uploader](https://github.com/Neembuu-Uploader/neembuu-uploader) development. You could check the [tutorial](http://neembuuuploader.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Identifying_the_HTTP_GET/POST_requests_for_upload) we wrote some years ago.

Comment: Yes, the response contains data you can see in http://www.gymnasiumleiden.nl/roostersinfoweb/infoweb/index.php after login.